# Robocode: How can I programatically compile a robot?

Tags: java, compilation, robot, robocode

I have created a program which generates Robocode robots, saving them as the usual .java files. The issue I am having is compiling them to be used in battles!
I need to do this automatically in code, but can't quite work it out.

Thanks!

Comment: set up a jenkins build server..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I used for this was to run an Operating System command to use javac to compile the java files which were produced.